# running application on android emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, windows-7, 32-bit

I am trying to run hello world program on andriod emulator using eclipse. emultor starts but my application never loads on emulator.
I thought it may be because of my windows version or slow RAM or processor.I am using windows 7 starter 32 bit, 1GB RAM , intel Atom 1.66 Ghz processor.can any one tell me what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

Please open the task manager and check the process status and CPU usage.
I guess CPU usage should be 100% when eclipse and emulator are running at the same time.

Emulator and Eclipse consume a large amount of memory while running.

Even I faced the same issue.

Ran the same program in a system with higher RAM and it ran smoothly.

I guess you are facing the same issue.

It will be helpful if you can paste what you are getting in Eclipse console.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the logs in the logcat .It is located in DDMS. It will give you the reason why the emulator is not starting. And also this problem is either related to a buggy code or a wrongly setup android project configuration. Because of slow ram and hardware it may load slowly but it will load eventually.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether the emulator has been recognized by eclipse or not. You can do it by opening DDMS and see list of devices, if your emulator is listed in devices then run the app. If the emulator is not listed in Devices then close the current emulator and try to start it again until you see the emulator on devices.